# Interoperation and CRL Activity

Tags: c#, c++, interop, clr

*I hope that question would not mess with StackOverFlow FAQ rules*

So ,when using Libraries which are written in C++ for example ,and that means we have some Code in these DLL's which is going to be executed ,when Software execution cames in that case ,will this Portion of code be executed by CLR ?

I need that because we plan to develop a Software and some Angry Algorithms i think will be better to program them in C++ ,but Visual C# serves us some tools that we cant find in c++ (Linq ,Anonymous etc) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DLLs created in C++ inside your C# project, and as you already know you have to make an interop call. This switches context to unsafe, so the code is probably executed outside the CLR. This means that you lose the portability options the CLR gives you. For example a C# based app would run on Windows and Windows Phone, but adding interop calls will only make it work on Windows (or whatever system the DLL was compiled for).

But normally this isn't much of an issue.

Also see this thread: http://forums.devshed.com/net-development-87/using-a-c-dll-in-c-107829.html

Comment: I think this application will be a Professional one ,and will have a very Specific Environment ,maybe we will require a Machine to run only that Application and Users cannot change at System nothing at all ,so Portability is not an issue ,just that handling with Unmanaged code will mess some things but also will Tune the app.